# windbg not print (show) kernel logs (with kdprint and other log function)

Tags: windows, debugging, driver, kmdf, wdm

I'm getting started learning windows kernel driver programming with wdm. I wrote my first driver which print some logs when that start (Entry) and stop (unload). I can see logs in debugview (dbgview.exe) but windbg cant get them.

I set

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter" to **0xf**

and run
**:> bcdedit /debug local**

Windows version: 2004 (build 1904)
WDK10 (build 1904)

why windbg couldn't get logs (but dbgview show them) ??
**Do I have to do anything else?**

Comment: Yes. I want to see kernel debug logs. but windbg not show testdriver log (but dbgview show them).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DbgPrintEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprintex) this api does not require editing reg key:

```
DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Hello Kernel");
```